# How do I replace text using a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a variable with a bunch of data.

```
text = "ABCDEFGHIJK"
file = garbage.txt //iiuhdsfiuhdsihf]sdiuhdfoidsoijsf
```

What I would like to do is replace the ] charachter in file with text.  I've tried using sed but I keep getting odd errors.

output should be:

```
//iiuhdsfiuhdsihfABCDEFGHIJKsdiuhdfoidsoijsf
```

Comment: which shell are you using? see if it allows space to be used around `=` for variable assignment...  and add the sed command you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Just need to escape the `]` character with a `\` in regex:

```
text="ABCDEFGHIJK"
sed "s/\(.*\)\]\(.*\)/\1$text\2/" file > file.changed
```

or, for in-place editing:

```
sed -i "s/\(.*\)\]\(.*\)/\1$text\2/" file
```

---

Test:

```
sed "s/\(.*\)\]\(.*\)/\1$text\2/" <<< "iiuhdsfiuhdsihf]sdiuhdfoidsoijsf"

# output => iiuhdsfiuhdsihfABCDEFGHIJKsdiuhdfoidsoijsf
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?  Did you run with the `-i` option or not?  I think the Mac version needs an argument to `-i`.  So, you can try `-i ''`.

Comment: You can try explicitly anchoring the expressions for the backreferences e.g. `sed "s/^\(.*\)\]\(.*$\)/\1$text\2/"`

Comment: I get an error `sed: 1: "s/\(.*\)\]\(.*\)/\1   { ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`

Comment: With -i I get `sed: 1: "../file.txt_ ...": invalid command code .`

Comment: I just checked an this works for me: `sed -i.bak "s/\(.*\)\]\(.*\)/\1$text\2/" file`.

Comment: @codeforester Looks like you're right.  My subsitution seems to have newlines that is causing the issue. (I used the $text variable as an example)

Answer (score 0):

There is always the bash way that should work in your osx:

```
filevar=$(cat file)
echo "${filevar/]/$text}" #to replace first occurence
OR
echo "${filevar//]/$text}" #to replace all occurences
```

In my bash i don't even have to escape `]`.

By the way, the simple sed does not work?

```
$ a="AA"
$ echo "garbage.txt //iiuhdsfiuhdsihf]sdiuhdfoidsoijsf" |sed "s/]/$a/g"
garbage.txt //iiuhdsfiuhdsihfAAsdiuhdfoidsoijsf
```